# Clickable scrolling image

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I have an activity which contains an image view that is scrollable -> the image is bigger than the phone's screen and therefore it is scrollable.

I want that several points of the image would be clickable.
how is it possible then if the image is scrollable and I also need to detect on which part of the image the user clicked?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll have to divide us the image in different portions if you want to provide that sort of functionality. Because an ImageView is one element which is capable of handling it's own trigger event for the whole image. It doesn't matter if you touch the middle, top-right, bottom-left, quarter to the right or anywhere. The only thing you can determine are the X and Y cordinators of where the touch was placed via the following function:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            String xCordinate = String.valueOf(event.getX()
            String yCordinate = String.valueOf(event.getY();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Additionally, if you want to handle a different events on a single image based on what part/portion of the image was clicked, you'll have to hide elements which will trigger the event. In this case, you can use a frameLayout with ImageView on the back and 4 buttons on the top (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right) and hide the buttons using the following code:

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And base your functionality around the onClickListener for the buttons.

Hope I am making sense.